# pressing the letter 'A' on the keyboard presses the ctrl keys

Tags: windows-10

Could somebody explain how to fix this? When pressing 'A' on my keyboard it acts like I'm pressing CTRL+A, and On-Screen Keyboard it shows that I'm pressing CTRL but at that time I'm just holding or pressing A letter. It won't write A letter but it takes the input.

I tried holding both CTRL buttons at the same time, also tried reinstalling the drivers, windows system updates, ctrl+shift for 15 sec. And other type of solutions like if my sticky keys are off  or keyboard troubleshoot and etc.

I'm using laptop keyboard on lenovo computer, if that helps.

Comment: Have you restarted? Have you tried an external USB keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an English keyboard, the <kbd>A</kbd> is right next to the
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, so seems to somehow stick to it.

I think that cleaning the keyboard is called for.
You might have some dirt or a small object that is stuck in there.

Try to turn the keyboard over to get the dirt out.
See also if you can see anything visually.

In the worst case, you will need to (carefully) pull out the two keys
and clean underneath them.